# How to get php to tell if it run is on iOS or MacOS

Tags: php, ios, iphone, macos

I have been attempting to run two different variations of my website: one for desktop and one for mobile. I decided to make it work like this (using PHP): if on Windows, Mac, or other desktop OS, run this HTML.  if on Android, iOS, etc. run that HTML. When I go to my website through Windows or Android, the HTML for the corresponding OS is run.  But when I go to my website through an iPhone or MacBook, both the code for iPhone AND Mac is run, regardless of if the user is on an iPhone or MacBook:  Here is the code I use:

```
<!--HTML for macOS --> 

 <?php
if(preg_match( '/macintosh|mac os x/i',  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {

echo' <!--some HTML--> ';  }  ?>


<!--HTML for iPhone--> 


    <?php

       ifif(preg_match('/iphone/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {

        echo' <!--some HTML-->  ';  }  ?>
```

If you want to observe the problem, go to bamfacts.tk  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use javascript.

```
 /* Check if mobile */

var isMobile = {
   Android: function() {
       return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
   },
   BlackBerry: function() {
       return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
   },
   iOS: function() {
       return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
   },
   Opera: function() {
       return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
   },
   Windows: function() {
       return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/WPDesktop/i);
   },
   any: function() {
       return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
   }
};   

if(isMobile.any())
{
 //this is mobile
}
```

Comment: It doesn't has a clause to check for OS X devices. The OP wants to distinguish between iOS and OSX, not general mobile platforms.

Answer (score 4):

Following Script will tell you if it is OS X or iOS. You just need to see what is the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` and you are good to go after using some regex or string operations.

```
<?php
// Apple detection array
$Apple = array();
$Apple['UA'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$Apple['Device'] = false;
$Apple['Types'] = array('iOS', 'Macintosh');
foreach ($Apple['Types'] as $d => $t) {
    $Apple[$t] = (strpos($Apple['UA'], $t) !== false);
    $Apple['Device'] |= $Apple[$t];
}
// is this an Apple device?
echo
    "<p>Apple device? ", ($Apple['Device'] ? 'true' : 'false'),
    "</p><p>iOS? ", ($Apple['iOS'] ? 'true' : 'false'),
    "</p><p>OS X? ", ($Apple['Macintosh'] ? 'true' : 'false'),
    '</p>';
?>
```

You can also do it with Java Script like following:

```
var Apple = {};
Apple.UA = navigator.userAgent;
Apple.Device = false;
Apple.Types = ["iOS", "Macintosh"];
for (var d = 0; d < Apple.Types.length; d++) {
    var t = Apple.Types[d];
    Apple[t] = !!Apple.UA.match(new RegExp(t, "i"));
    Apple.Device = Apple.Device || Apple[t];
}

// is this an Apple device?
alert(
    "Is it an Apple device? " + Apple.Device +
    " \nIs it iOS? " + Apple.iOS +
    " \nIs it OSX? " + Apple.Macintosh
);
```

You can see the Javascript fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6dfp919a/).

Comment: I would like to thank you for your help, but when I tested this exact code (and another variation), I got true for iPhone (which I wanted), but also true for Mac.  This is the problem that made me ask the above question.  I think this as to do with the user agent string, but still leaves me with the problem...

Comment: Also you are correct this is because of user agent string. For iphone, the string also has "Like Mac OS X" due to which regex and string comparison fails and becomes true for both. Doing it for keywords iOS and Macintosh however works because those are unique

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a goed idea, why not use a responsive design. Like Foundation (http://foundation.zurb.com/) of Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/). Or make something yourself (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

Responsive basically means the site scales to the format of the screen the visitor is using (phone, tablet, latop, large desktop). This way your site is working on every devise instead of making a site for every devise.

Comment: Well, I do use a responsive design, but I also have a different navigation menu for mobile and desktop.  Go to  Bamfacts.tk and use the F12 Chrome Dev. options to see what I mean.

Comment: That explains it. Normally I use two menu's and some CSS (hide-mobile, show-mobile)